# Twilio API - getting the child call SID after Status Callback

Tags: twilio

I am using a TwiML App to establish a phone call via the browser.
I have a Status Callback URL in the APp that post the details of the child call.

The problem is, in the POST I only have the Parent Call ID, not the actual child call ID. How can I get it?

The post looks something like:

> post: ApiVersion=2010-04-01&Called=&CallStatus=completed&Duration=1&From=client%3Akaren_calls&CallDuration=20&Timestamp=Mon%2C%2025%20May%202015%2020%3A48%3A22%20%2B0000&Direction=inbound&CallbackSource=call-progress-events&AccountSid=ACfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&ApplicationSid=xxxxxxxxxxxx&Caller=client%3Akaren_calls&SequenceNumber=0&To=&CallSid=CAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

The "CallSid" above is for the parent call, not the child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get the child calls of a call by retrieving a list of calls from the REST API and filtering it by the parent call SID. You can see how you can [filter calls in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters).

If you were doing this with the Ruby library, you would do the following:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

# Fill in your account SID and auth token below
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new "ACxxxx", "XYzzzzz"

# Fill in the call SID below
child_calls = client.calls.list parent_call_sid: "CAxxxxx"
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I use PHP, but that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I am using something like:

<code>
$calls = $client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        "ParentCallSid" => "CAxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     ));


foreach ($calls as $call) {
    echo $call->sid . "<br>";
    echo $call->from . "<br>";
    echo $call->to . "<br>";
    echo $call->start_time . "<br>";
    echo $call->end_time . "<br>";
    echo $call->duration . "<br>";
    echo $call->parent_call_sid . "<br>";
    echo $call->status . "<br>";
    echo $call->price . "<br>";
}
</code>

Comment: any chance there's the node variant for this with the `twilio.TwimlResponse()` response?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Where can i read more about ParantCallSid, ChildCallSid. How/when and why they are created? and which callSid is best to extract pricing info as parentCallSid say prcing on 0.0025 while a child callSid say a pricing of 0.025          ???

Comment: The ParentCallSid is the originating call, ChildCallSids are any call created during that call (for example the outbound call generated by a `<Dial>` in response to an incoming call). The total price of a call between two people is the price of the parent call plus the price of the child call. You pay for both legs of the call (inbound and outbound) and they may be different lengths.

Comment: I wish the topic of child callsid and parent callsid and how they relate to the API was a lot more explicit in Twilio's documentation

Comment: So you're telling me that, if I want to grab all calls and their legs, I need to make one request to get all the parent calls (`list`) and then loop through each of those resources, making another `list` call with the `parent_call_sid` as a parameter, for each parent call? Give me a break...

Comment: @JordanF that is correct, though you could store that relationship ahead of time using the information in the webhooks relating to the call if you know you’re going to need this.